# Load but not show the output (AB Test: Control x Variant)

Tags: javascript, testing, user-experience

I would like to run an AB test implementing a Javascript code in the variant.
But, it's important that both pages have the same page load time.

The control page needs to run the variant code, but without showing the output (for example, changing a color button).
Meanwhile, the variant page executes the same code, but showing the output.

So, if the code affects the page load time, both versions will be affected and the user experience will be the same. The reliability of the test won't be interfered.

Variant:

```
document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.innerText = "newlabel";
```

Control:

```
DoNotShow{
document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.innerText = "newlabel";}
```

How can I do this kind of thing?

I have to run an AB Test. The control and variant needs to execute the same code, to avoid the code affects the page load time and the reliability of the test.

But, as the control will run the same code, I would like to know how to do not show the output.